# function plotting html website

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, plot

i hope anyone can help me with my code...
It´s a plotting html, where you can type in a function (f(x)) with only x variables and get a plotted graph for an intervall you type in.
The part where everything is replaced with stuff javascript can eval() works,
as far as i tested.

There are 2 problems that I can´t make out why it happens:

1) X-axis numbers are kinda delayed for 1 step,
but i used it like the y-axis and that one worked...
the lines are drawn normal but the numbers on them don´t want to fit...
2) the graph itself is kinda drawn, but not properly,
like if i missed a value, but I don´t know what that could be...
(it´s some kind of offset on the x-axis)

Why would it be interesting for others?
Because a lot of people may want to do a plotter or similar like that or want to know how to replace the "x^y" with "Math.pow(x,y)" and stuff.

I hope this time the editing works...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="plotter.css" media="all">
        </head>
        <body>
                <div class="aussenrand">
                        <div class="canvasdiv">
                                <canvas id="canvas"class="canvas" height="500" width="800">
                                Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mittediv">
                                <div class="fktn1">
                                                <table>
                                                        <tr><td><button onclick="replZirkumflex(eingabeF1,plotYVal)">Berechnen</button></td></tr>
                                                        <tr><td><label for="DBXmin"> xmin:<input id="DBXmin" placeholder="0"></label></td></tr>
                                                        <tr><td><label for="DBXmax"> xmax:<input id="DBXmax" placeholder="20"></label></td></tr>
                                                        <tr><td><label for="schritte"> Schrittweite: <input id="schritte" placeholder="0.1"></label></td></tr>
                                                        <tr><td><label for="funktion1"> Funktion: <input id="funktion1" placeholder="0"></label></td></tr>
                                                        <tr><td><button onclick="draw()">Zeichnen</button></td></tr>
                                                </table>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <script>
//global used variables
                        var plotYVal =[];
                        var xplotmin = 0;
                        var xplotmax = 1;
                        var stepval = 0.1;
                        //color not implemented yet
                        var colorF1 = "";
                        //function you typed in
                        var eingabeF1;
                        var roundScal = "8";
                        var bufferFktn = "";
                        var minimum = 0;
                        var maximum = 1;
                        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

                        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                        function replZirkumflex(eingabeF1,plotYVal){
                                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
//to see, if any of the fields are empty and print an alert
                                xplotmin = document.getElementById("DBXmin").value;
                                xplotmin = xplotmin.replace(/"[^0-9]",""/g);
                                        if(xplotmin == ""){alert("Bitte ein Minimum angeben."); return;}
                                xplotmin = parseFloat(xplotmin);

                                xplotmax = document.getElementById("DBXmax").value;
                                xplotmax = xplotmax.replace(/"[^0-9]",""/g);
                                        if(xplotmax == ""){alert("Bitte ein Maximum angeben."); return;}
                                xplotmax = parseFloat(xplotmax);

                                stepval = document.getElementById("schritte").value;
                                stepval = stepval.replace(/"[^0-9]",""/g);
                                        if(stepval == "") {alert("Bitte eine Schrittweite angeben."); return;}
                                stepval = parseFloat(stepval);

                                eingabeF1 = document.getElementById("funktion1").value;
                                        if(eingabeF1 == "") {alert("Bitte eine Funktion angeben."); return;}
//replace everything needed, so that eval() can understand it
                                var PosMath = eingabeF1;
                                var SIN = PosMath.replace("sin", "Math.sin");
                                PosMath = SIN;
                                var COS = PosMath.replace("cos", "Math.cos");
                                PosMath = COS;
                                var TAN = PosMath.replace("tan","Math.tan");
                                PosMath = TAN;
                                var SQRT = PosMath.replace("sqrt","Math.sqrt");
                                PosMath = SQRT;
                                var LOG = PosMath.replace("log","Math.log");
                                PosMath = LOG;
                                eingabeF1 = PosMath;

                                var strZirk = eingabeF1;
                                //count the amount of "^"
                                var pos = 0;
                                var amZirk = -1; //amount "^"
                                var i = -1;
                                while (pos != -1) {
                                        pos = strZirk.indexOf("^", i + 1);
                                        amZirk += 1;
                                        i = pos;}
                                var delZirk = "";
                                var LVSubL = 0;
                                LVZirk = 0;
                                //as long as there are "^"
                                while(amZirk > 0){
                                        //Suche nach Positionen von "^"
                                        var strPow = eingabeF1;
                                        var indicesPow = [];
                                        for(var i=0; i<strPow.length;i++) {
                                                if (strPow[i] === "^"){
                                                        indicesPow.push(i);}
                                        }
                                        //Linksseitig
                                        var LVSuchL = eingabeF1.match(/(\+|\-|\*|\/)/g);
                                        var strSuchL = eingabeF1;
                                        while(LVSuchL != null && LVSubL < indicesPow[LVZirk]){
                                                var strSuchL = strSuchL.substring(1,indicesPow[LVZirk]);
                                                LVSuchL = strSuchL.match(/(\+|\-|\*|\/)/g);
                                                LVSubL += 1;
                                        }
                                        var EXLinks = eingabeF1.substring(LVSubL,indicesPow[LVZirk]); //-1
                                        EXLinks = "Math.pow(" + EXLinks + ",";
                                        //Rechtsseitig
                                        var LVSubRA = indicesPow[LVZirk]+1;
                                        var LVSubRB = eingabeF1.length;
                                        var strSuchR = eingabeF1.substring(LVSubRA, LVSubRB);
                                        var LVSuchR = strSuchR.match(/(\+|\-|\*|\/)/g);
                                        while(LVSubRA < LVSubRB && LVSuchR != null){
                                                strSuchR = eingabeF1.substring(LVSubRA, LVSubRB);
                                                LVSuchR = strSuchR.match(/(\+|\-|\*|\/)/g);
                                                LVSubRB -=1;
                                                }
                                                LVSubRB +=1;
                                        var EXRechts = eingabeF1.substring(LVSubRA,LVSubRB);
                                        var replPow = EXLinks + EXRechts + ")";
                                        var delZirk = eingabeF1.substring(0,LVSubL) + replPow + eingabeF1.substring(LVSubRB,eingabeF1.length); //powered by hannes
                                        eingabeF1 = delZirk;
                                        amZirk -= 1;
                                        LVSubL += replPow.length;
                                        LVSubL +=1;
                                }
//calculation
                                        bufferFktn = eingabeF1;
                                        var xBer = parseFloat(xplotmin);
                                        while (xBer < (xplotmax+stepval)) {
                                                var bufferFktn = eingabeF1.replace(/x/g, xBer);
                                                var ywert = eval(bufferFktn).toFixed(roundScal);
                                                plotYVal.push(ywert);
                                                xBer +=stepval;
                                        }
                                //Extrema
                                var findMin = plotYVal;
                                Array.min = function( findMin ){ return Math.min.apply( Math, findMin ); };
                                minimum = Array.min(findMin);
                                var findMax = plotYVal;
                                Array.max = function( findMax ){ return Math.max.apply( Math, findMax ); };
                                maximum = Array.max(findMax);
                                //alert("Minimum: " + minimum + " und Maximum: " + maximum);
                        }
//draw
                        function draw() {
                        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                                if (null==canvas || !canvas.getContext) return;
                        var axes={};
                        //Mittelpunkt
                        axes.x0 = .5 + .5*canvas.width;  // x0 pixels from left to x=0
                        axes.y0 = .5 + .5*canvas.height; // y0 pixels from top to y=0
                        axes.scale = 1;
                        axes.doNegativeX = true;
                        showAxes(ctx,axes);
                        graph(ctx,minimum,maximum);
                        }

                        function showAxes(ctx,axes) {
                        //axes
                                var x0=axes.x0, w=ctx.canvas.width;
                                var y0=axes.y0, h=ctx.canvas.height;
                                var xmin = axes.doNegativeX ? 0 : x0;
                                ctx.beginPath();
                                ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(128,128,128)";
                                ctx.moveTo(xmin,y0); ctx.lineTo(w,y0);  // X axis
                                ctx.moveTo(x0,0);    ctx.lineTo(x0,h);  // Y axis

//numbers on the axes
/*
This is where the stuff goes horribly wrong on the x-axis
*/
                                ctx.font = "15px serif";
                        //Y-axis
                                var yi = parseInt(0);
                                var yAchsBeschr = parseInt(0);
                                        if(Math.abs(minimum) < Math.abs(maximum)) yAchsBeschr = Math.abs(maximum);
                                        if(Math.abs(minimum) > Math.abs(maximum)) yAchsBeschr = Math.abs(minimum);
                                        if(Math.abs(minimum) == Math.abs(maximum)) yAchsBeschr = Math.abs(maximum);
                                var yAchs = parseInt(0);

                                        while(yi < 21){
                                                if(yi==9){
                                                        yAchsBeschr = parseFloat(yAchsBeschr - (maximum/10)).toFixed(1);
                                                        ctx.moveTo(axes.x0 - 5,yAchs); ctx.lineTo(axes.x0 + 5,yAchs);
                                                        ctx.fillText("", axes.x0 + 10, yAchs+(canvas.height/20)+4);
                                                        yAchs +=(canvas.height/20);
                                                        yi++;
                                                        }
                                                if(yi!=9){
                                                        yAchsBeschr = parseFloat(yAchsBeschr - (maximum/10)).toFixed(1);
                                                        ctx.moveTo(axes.x0 - 5,yAchs); ctx.lineTo(axes.x0 + 5,yAchs);
                                                        ctx.fillText(yAchsBeschr, axes.x0 + 10, yAchs+(canvas.height/20)+4);
                                                        yAchs +=(canvas.height/20);
                                                        yi++;
                                                        }
                                        }
                        //X-axis
                                var xi = parseInt(0);
                                var xAchsBeschr;
                                var xAchs = parseInt(0);
                                var xLauf = parseInt(0);
                                        if(Math.abs(xplotmin) < Math.abs(xplotmax))  xAchsBeschr = xLauf = Math.abs(xplotmax);
                                        if(Math.abs(xplotmin) > Math.abs(xplotmax))  xAchsBeschr = xLauf  = Math.abs(xplotmin);
                                        if(Math.abs(xplotmin) == Math.abs(xplotmax)) xAchsBeschr = xLauf  = Math.abs(xplotmax);

                                        while(xi<21){
                                                if(xi== 10){
                                                        xAchsBeschr = parseFloat(-xLauf+(xi*xLauf/10)).toFixed(1);
                                                        ctx.moveTo(xAchs,axes.y0 - 5); ctx.lineTo(xAchs,axes.y0 + 5);
                                                        ctx.fillText("", xAchs+(canvas.width/20)-4, axes.y0 + 18);
                                                        xAchs +=(canvas.width/20);
                                                        xi++;}
                                                if (xi!=10){
                                                        xAchsBeschr = parseFloat(-xLauf+(xi*xLauf/10)).toFixed(1);
                                                        ctx.moveTo(xAchs,axes.y0 - 5); ctx.lineTo(xAchs,axes.y0 + 5);
                                                        ctx.fillText(xAchsBeschr, xAchs+(canvas.width/20)-4, axes.y0 + 18);
                                                        xAchs +=(canvas.width/20);
                                                        xi++;
                                                        }
                                        }
                                ctx.stroke();
                        }
                        function graph(ctx,minimum,maximum){
                                var graphHeight = parseInt(0);
                                var i = parseInt(0);
                                        if(Math.abs(minimum) < Math.abs(maximum)) graphHeight = Math.abs(maximum);
                                        if(Math.abs(minimum) > Math.abs(maximum)) graphHeight = Math.abs(minimum);
                                        if(Math.abs(minimum) == Math.abs(maximum)) graphHeight = Math.abs(maximum);

                                ctx.moveTo(i*(canvas.width)*stepval/plotYVal.length, plotYVal[i]*canvas.height*2/graphHeight);
                                i++;
                                while(i<plotYVal.length){
                                        ctx.lineTo(i*(canvas.width)*stepval/plotYVal.length, plotYVal[i]*canvas.height/graphHeight)
                                        ctx.stroke();
                                        i++;
                                        //alert(i*canvas.width*stepval/plotYVal.length + " / " + plotYVal[i]*canvas.height/graphHeight);
                                        }

                        }
                        /*
that´s the code that worked BEFORE I did the stuff with the numbers on the axes
                                var scalres = (canvas.height/((Math.abs(minimum)+Math.abs(maximum))));
                                var Xadd;
                                Xadd = parseFloat(minimum);
                                i = parseInt(0);
                                while(i < plotYVal.length){
                                        if (i==0) ctx.moveTo(parseFloat((canvas.width/2)+(Xadd)), canvas.height - ((canvas.height/2)+(plotYVal[i]*scalres)));
                                        else ctx.lineTo(parseFloat((canvas.width/2)+(Xadd)), canvas.height - ((canvas.height/2)+(plotYVal[i]*scalres)));
                                i++;
                                Xadd +=parseFloat(stepval);
                                }
                                ctx.stroke();
                        }*/
                </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

If the stuff isn´t displayed properly:
http://pastebin.com/hKgq0kCj

Has anyone a hint why it doesn´t work out?

Would be really nice

Comment: Please look through the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).

Comment: What exactly there? I read the guidelines, if you meant that. And i thought these tags were helpful.

Comment: This [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) asks you to post your code directly on SO rather thank link it. Also, you don't have the badge for taking the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). I would highly recommend it. Last, the [editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) describes how to format your text. This was linked on the right hand side of the screen when you posted your question.

Comment: Also, I didn't have an opinion about your tags. But, you asked how to format your code and you weren't following other posting suggestions.

Comment: Finally I got the idea behind that "Indent four spaces to create an escaped ..." Would have been easier to say "hey, just mark your code and press that button there...And i was following the help pages and the tour. The system explaing how to "tag" code isn´t logically explained (imo) or proper explained. And i got this badge when i wrote the post 2 hours ago.